# use scipy.stats.linregress on two pandas dataframes output variables in new dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, scipy

I currently have two dataframes with the same dimension (rows=dates, columns=stations) one dataframe holds the number of times an occurrence happens per day and the other is a temperature difference per day. I would like to run scipy.stats.linregress on each column of the two dataframes and store the output variables into another dataframe where the axis are (rows=Stations, Columns=output or reversed doesn't matter). The only examples I have see online are using only one dataframe and not two (with the exception of corr_with() which only gives me the r-value, but I also need the slope, intercept, p-value, and stderr for each station given the temperature difference as X and the occurrences as Y)

Is there a easy pandas method to this I am missing or should I take the brute force approach through loops?

[image: Image of my two Dataframes]

Comment: Can you add an example of your data to the question? (e.g. the first few rows of each of your two dataframes?)

Comment: Yes I will in the morning when I get back to my computer. Thank you.

Comment: added example requested